# Android Load Image from Drawable

Tags: android, image

i need to create a object Image from import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image; using a file .png placed in drawable folder. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the javax.microedition.lcdui.Image?  Will Bitmap not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this Android and not JavaME, you cannot create a  javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.  You would create a Bitmap instead.  [Here's](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/3748281) a decent tutorial on working with images in Android.

Comment: hi, the problem is i need use this libray:

http://www.nutiteq.com/javadoc/index.html and i need javax.Image... thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?